# inspect the gstreamer pipeline in cheese

Tags: gstreamer

I am currently trying to stream from my webcam to my ARM device and while I can get it to stream a few frames, my pipeline does not work perfectly and sometimes it hangs and sometimes it drops frames or has other errors.

On the other hand, I notice that `cheese` seems to stream from my webcam just fine. I was wondering if it is possible to inspect the gstreamer pipeline used by `cheese` somehow, so that I can try and replicate it on ym app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try setting `GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR=<log dir>` in your environment variables before running the application. After exiting the application you may end up with some .dot files in the given directory. These files can be read or converted to image files with tools from the `graphviz` package.